# SP13 - How to delete folder(and their content) in document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, folder, delete

I want to delete folder and their content in document library

**Structure:**

```
Document Library
-- Folder(delete this)
--- image.jpg(delete this)
```

**This is my Code:**

```
SPFolder myFolder = oWebBG.GetFolder(urlFolderSmallEN);
myFolder.Recycle();
```

When I delete the folder, it will delete its contents as well. I have no subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below code to delete folder or sub-folder form document library

```
String siteURL = "http://<<SharePoint URL>>";
String libraryName = "<<LibraryName>>";
String folderToDelete = "<<FolderName>>";

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPFolderCollection folders = web.Folders[libraryName ].SubFolders;

        foreach (SPFolder folder in folders)
        {
            if (folder.Name == folderToDelete)
            {
               web.Folders[libraryName ].SubFolders.Delete(folder.Url);
            }
        }                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code works good for my case:**

```
 if (FolderExists(urlFolder, oWeb))
 {
     SPFolder myFolder = oWeb.GetFolder(urlFolder);
     myFolder.Recycle(); //delete folder and content
 }
```

**Check Folder exist:**

```
        static bool FolderExists(string url, SPWeb web)
        {
           try
           {
              if (web.GetFolder(url).Exists)
              {
                   return true;
              }
              return false;
           }
           catch (ArgumentException)
           {
                return false;
           }
       }
```